# How to set shape in QGraphicsPolygonItem which have subpath?

Tags: pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I try to draw a polygon and the polygon with some join points.But when i create it's shape, the path that have a `CircleItem` shadow .That is not I wanted.

**the code**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal as Signal
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty as Property
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import *

class CircleItem(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        # self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable|QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setBrush(Qt.red)

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addEllipse(-20, -20, 40, 40)
        self.setPath(path)

class PolyItem(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        poly = QPolygonF([
            QPointF(200, -0),
            QPointF(120, 150)
        ])

        self.circles = []
        for pt in poly:
            c = CircleItem(self)
            c.setPos(pt)
            self.circles.append(c)

        self.setPolygon(poly)

    def shape(self) -> QPainterPath:
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addPolygon(self.polygon())

        for c in self.circles:
            path.addPath(c.path())

        return path

    def boundingRect(self) -> QRectF:
        return self.shape().boundingRect()

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option: 'QStyleOptionGraphicsItem', widget) -> None:
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())

        painter.setPen(Qt.blue)
        painter.drawPath(self.shape())
        return super().paint(painter, option, widget)

class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pl = PolyItem()
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
        self.scene().addItem(pl)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = View()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

**the result**
[image]

Comment: Neither `shape()` nor `boundingRect()` are intended to provide means for painting: the former is for collision detection, the latter to define the region in which redraws will be restricted (necessary for proper updates and painting optimization). Is that "bounding rectangle" painting necessary for your needs?

Comment: The demo I give have a bug. in shape function everytime add subpath, the subpath always at (0,0), so the subpath not really add in the shape.

Comment: I know where the "bug" is, that's not what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PolyItem` is a `QGraphicsPolygonItem`, so it inherits all from `QGraphicsPolygonItem`, then you can treat it like a `QGraphicsPolygonItem`:

```py
poly = QPolygonF([
  QPointF(200, -0),
  QPointF(120, 150),
  QPointF(100, 100),
  QPointF( 20,  50)
])

pl = PolyItem( poly )
```

To test it quickly without your blue balls, you can build a PolyItem that is doing nothing:

```py
class PolyItem(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
  def __init__(self, polyParam):
    super().__init__(polyParam)
```

Now that you have the basis, you want to improve `PolyItem`:

```py
class PolyItem(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
  def __init__(self, polyParam):
    super().__init__(polyParam)
    for pt in polyParam:
      c = BlueBall(pt)
```

But, here inside `PolyItem().__init__()`, I want to add my `BlueBall()` **on the scene**.
So, I have no choice, I must add scene as a parameter:

```py
class PolyItem(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
  def __init__(self, scene, polyParam):
    super().__init__(polyParam)

    for pt in polyParam:
      c = BlueBall( pt )
      scene.addItem( c )
```

Then, that's it.

Below the complete code

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class BlueBall(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
  def __init__(self, initialPosMove):
    radius= 20
    super().__init__(0,0,radius*2,radius*2)
    self.setPen(Qt.blue)
    self.setPos( initialPosMove - QPointF(radius,radius) )

class PolyItem(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
  def __init__(self, scene, polyParam ):
    super().__init__( polyParam )

    for pt in polyParam:
      c = BlueBall( pt )
      scene.addItem( c )

class View(QGraphicsView):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.scene= QGraphicsScene()
    self.setScene( self.scene )

    poly = QPolygonF([
      QPointF(200, -0),
      QPointF(120, 150),
      QPointF(100, 100),
      QPointF( 20,  50)
    ])

    pl = PolyItem(self.scene, poly)
    # pl = QGraphicsPolygonItem(poly)
    self.scene.addItem(pl)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication([])
  win = View()
  win.show()
  app.exec()
```

[image]